# How to pass Version/PackageVersion parameter to DotNet Core CLi

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

I'm using Github Package Registry for my own nuget packages. Here is my dotnet nuget push command.

```
dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/${ProjectName}.${PackageVersion}.nupkg" --source <MY_NUGET_SOURCE> --api-key <MY_API_KEY>
```

- `${ProjectName}` -> Works fine and gives the selected project's name.
- `${PackageVersion}` or `${Version}` -> Doesn't work for me.

I want to pass the `Version/PackageVersion` value where is defined in `.csproj` too. How can I do that?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTags>Some tags</PackageTags>
    <Title>SomeTitle</Title>
    <RepositoryUrl>My RepositoryUrl</RepositoryUrl>
    <PackageId>MyPackageId</PackageId>
    <PackageVersion>1.0.6</PackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: You can try `<VersionPrefix>1.0.6</VersionPrefix>`.

Comment: I've tried just now but unfortunately it didn't work. Here is error: File does not exist `(bin/Debug/MyProjectName.${VersionPrefix}.nupkg)`

Comment: You try use `$(Version)` or `$(VersionPrefix)`?

Comment: Version doesn't works with curly braces ${Version}. But it works fine with brackets $(Version). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(Version)` instead `${Version}`